# NetworkOnMainThreadExeption TCP Connection AsinkTask

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask, tcpclient

I have a problem, i'm trying to do a connection to my local tcp server, to upload an image. But i doesn't work and I did made the connection into a asinktask method. Did anybody know where i can come from.

```
public class ComplexFTPTransfer extends AsyncTask<File, Long[], Void>
{



    String server = "192.168.1.145";
    int port = 21;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        try {
            ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login("marc", "1234");
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            System.out.println("!>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            this.cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.cancel(true);
        }

        CameraActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(File... params) {
        if(!this.isCancelled())
        {
            try 
            {

                InputStream item = null;

                try {
                    item = new FileInputStream(params[0]);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                int streamSize = 0;
                while(item.read() != -1)
                {
                    streamSize++;
                }

                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(item, streamSize);
                OutputStream os = ftpClient.storeFileStream("/test.jpg");

                Util.copyStream(is, os, streamSize, streamSize, new CopyStreamListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {
                        publishProgress(new Long[] {totalBytesTransferred, streamSize});
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void bytesTransferred(CopyStreamEvent event) {

                    }
                });
                ftpClient.completePendingCommand();

                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();

            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long[]... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.d("UPDATE", values[0] + " of " + values[1] + " copied.");
        //TODO Put code here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        CameraActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

Here is method,

And i Called it here on activity result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    Bitmap bitmap;

    String path= "";
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {

        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

        path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); //from Gallery

        Log.i("Here", "Here we are");
        if (path == null)

            path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); //from File Manager

        if (path != null)
            Log.i("Here", path);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    } else {
        path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    }



    /*
    Mat gray_img = new Mat();
    Mat rgb_img = new Mat();

    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, rgb_img);                                 
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb_img, gray_img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    FeatureDetector surfDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor surfDescriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);


    Vector<Mat> surfDescriptors = new Vector<Mat>();
    MatOfKeyPoint vector = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    Mat descriptor = new Mat();
    surfDetector.detect( rgb_img, vector );
    surfDescriptor.compute(rgb_img, vector, descriptor);
    surfDescriptors.add(descriptor);
    String [] stringSurf = surfDescriptors.toArray(new String[0]);

     */

    File firstLocalFile = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());








    ftpTransfert = new ComplexFTPTransfer();
    ftpTransfert.execute(firstLocalFile);


    networktask = new NetworkTask();
    networktask.execute();


    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

And here is my log errors :

```
 09-11 15:41:49.640: W/dalvikvm(17995): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995): Process: com.test.camera_zero, PID: 17995
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.test.camera_zero/com.test.camera_zero.CameraActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:182)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at com.test.camera_zero.CameraActivity$ComplexFTPTransfer.onPreExecute(CameraActivity.java:401)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at com.test.camera_zero.CameraActivity.onActivityResult(CameraActivity.java:203)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
    09-11 15:41:49.640: E/AndroidRuntime(17995):    ... 11 more

`
```

Thanks to all.
Sorry for my mistake in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code , I have removed network calls from onPreexecute and added it in doInBackground. You can't call network methods in UI thread

```
public class ComplexFTPTransfer extends AsyncTask<File, Long[], Void>
```

{

```
String server = "192.168.1.145";
int port = 21;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    CameraActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(File... params) {
  try {
        ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login("marc", "1234");
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        System.out.println("!>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        this.cancel(true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.cancel(true);
    }


    if(!this.isCancelled())
    {
        try 
        {

            InputStream item = null;

            try {
                item = new FileInputStream(params[0]);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            int streamSize = 0;
            while(item.read() != -1)
            {
                streamSize++;
            }

            InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(item, streamSize);
            OutputStream os = ftpClient.storeFileStream("/test.jpg");

            Util.copyStream(is, os, streamSize, streamSize, new CopyStreamListener() {

                @Override
                public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {
                    publishProgress(new Long[] {totalBytesTransferred, streamSize});
                }

                @Override
                public void bytesTransferred(CopyStreamEvent event) {

                }
            });
            ftpClient.completePendingCommand();

            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Long[]... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    Log.d("UPDATE", values[0] + " of " + values[1] + " copied.");
    //TODO Put code here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    CameraActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to move all your networking code to the async task `doInBackground()`. At the moment you have the `ftpClient` setup networking code in `onPreExecute()` which runs on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

well, either

```
  ftpClient.connect(server, port);
  ftpClient.login("marc", "1234");
```

requires network interaction and since you are executing those in onPreExecute, that in turn runs on the UI Thread, the `NetworkOnMainThreadExecption` is thrown. You should move all the network related stuff in `doInBackground`